# Alternative method for performSelector in SKAction in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, swift

I'm converting a Sprikit App to Swift. But I have a problem to convert this method:

```
SKAction *releaseBalls = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction performSelector:@selector(createMyNode) onTarget:self],[SKAction waitForDuration:1]    ]];
```

Is there any alternative code in Swift ? Thanks

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: @0x7fffffff That method doesn't exist in Swift, it's obj-c only.

Comment: Just use `runBlock` instead and in the closure, call `self.createMyNode`.

Comment: Depending upon what your performing inside the method/function "createMyNode", you should exercise caution, as "SKAction.runBlock()" is really accepting a closure in Swift, which may raise the potential of strong reference cycle. According to docs SKAction.runBlock accepts a perimeter of type "dispatch_block_t!" which is defined as "typealias dispatch_block_t = () -> Void"

Comment: You can define a capture list for the closure to avoid the strong reference cycle.

`SKAction.runBlock() { [unowned self] () in self.createMyNode() }` Check it out in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-XID_61).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this out

```
class MyScene: SKScene {

    func doAction() {
        let releaseBalls = SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.runBlock(self.createMyNode),
            SKAction.waitForDuration(1)
            ])
        // run action
    }

    func createMyNode() {
        // create the nodes
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! When using this and calling class.doAction(), I get an error in Xcode saying: "Could not find an overload for doAction that accepts the supplied arguments" Am I missing something?

Comment: Jose, are you calling `MyScene.doAction()`, or calling `doAction` on an instance of `MyScene` ( `var scene: MyScene = MyScene(); scene.doAction()`)? The fact that you describe it as `class.doAction()` makes me think that you're trying to run `doAction` as a class method instead of as an instance method.

Comment: Great answer, or simply use: `SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock({run_some_code(); run_other_code()}), SKAction.waitForDuration(3)])` instead of `SKAction.runBlock(self.createMyNode)` (that ';' is needed as an separator!)

Comment: @JoséMaría you need to remove `()` e.g. `SKAction.runBlock(class.doAction)`. I bit late, but encounter the same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Although other solutions are generally preferred, future readers might like to know that `performSelector` and other members of the same family are available as of Swift 2.